# Duda Consulta SQL dos tablas doble clave

Tags: sql

Quiero pillar de un PARTIDO los campos equipo y escudo_ruta del local y visitante. Como podría ser ya que con un inner join solo pilla un equipo... Saludos!

[image: Imagen del diseño]

Comment: Con dos `INNER JOIN`, uno para local y otro para visitante.

Comment: Deberias mostrar como lo intentaste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado un partido, haz join dos veces a la tabla `equipo` para obtener los datos de ambos.

En otras palabras, haces el primer `join` a la tabla `equipo` para obtener los datos del local, y el segundo para obtener los datos del visitante, por ejemplo:

```
select   p.fecha
       , p.hora
       , el.equipo local_equipo
       , el.escudo_ruta local_escudo_ruta
       , p.resultado_local
       , ev.equipo visitante_equipo
       , ev.escudo_ruta visitante_escudo_ruta
       , p.resultado_visitante
  from partido p
       inner join equipo el on el.id = p.local
       inner join equipo ev on ev.id = p.visitante
 where p.id = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Como te comenta @Sal lo logras con 2 inner join

Ejemplo:

```
select t1.equipo, t2.equipo
from equipo
inner join partido as t1 on equipo.id = t1.local
inner join partido as t2 on equipo.id = t2.visitante
```